# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Error in mule 4 bulk insert into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, anypoint-studio, mule4

The payload is in json formatted string as follows. The date is giving me the above mentioned error. Why is that when the required varchar format is correct in `Created_Date`?
The insert query is

```
INSERT INTO SAPHDS_Inbound_Landing_Table(
Builder,Created_Date,Builder_Name,Builder_Abbrev,
Street_Address,City,State,Postal_code,Builder_Acct_Group,
Status,Record_Change_Date) 
values (:Builder,:Created_Date,:Builder_Name,:Builder_Abbrev,
:Street_Address,:City,:State,:Postal_Code,:Builder_Acct_Group,
:Status,:Record_Change_Date);
```

```
output application/json
---
payload map {
    'Builder': $.BUILDER default "",
    'Builder_Abbrev': $.BUILDER_ABBREV_CODE default "",
    'Builder_Acct_Group': $.BUILDER_AGROUP default "",
    'Builder_Name': $.BUILDER_NAME default "",
    'City': $.BUILDER_CITY default "",
    'Created_Date': (now() >> "US/Arizona") as String{format:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"} ,
    'Postal_Code': $.BUILDER_PCODE default "",
    'Record_Change_Date': $.CHANGE_DATE ,
    'State': $.BUILDER_STATE default "",
    'Status': $.BUILDER_STATUS default "",
    'Street_Address': $.BUILDER_STREET default "",
    'Integration_Status':'P',
    'SAP_API_Function': p('builder.sapAPIFunction')
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that actually inserts this into SQL

Comment: I have posted the insert query for mssql server bulk insert

Comment: I don't know anything about anypoint-studio, but if you  just want to populate the database field `Created_Date` with now, you can do it in the database.

Comment: You posted only the SQL query but not the complete Mule message processor, ie the XML surrounding the SQL. Also you should post the *complete* error message so it possible to understand better what could be the type problem. Additionally add the table structure, to understand what the DB expects. Also, though I see it in the tag sql-server it is better to mention the DB engine explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Created_Date field in DB to nvarchar or datetime and see if it helps.